# Angular search scope for value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to create a function that checks my scope for the value of status and returns true if it equals 1.

Here is my array:

```
"review": {
    "currentStep": 7,
    "stepA": {
      "status": 0,
    },
    "stepB": {
      "status": 1,
      "id": 1,
      "url": "http://placehold.it/2000x200"
    },
    "stepB": {
      "status": 0,
    },
}
```

I then have a function like so:

```
$scope.checkStatus = function(){}
```

Comment: Have you read the angular docs for $watch()?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out and this is the answer for anyone that may need it in the future:

```
$scope.checkStatus = function(){

    var reviewArray = $.map($scope.review, function (value) { return value; });     
    var status = $filter('filter')(reviewArray, { status: 1 });

    if(status.length > 0) {
        return true;
    }

}
```